# Invalid output and loop is not breaking in this bash code

Tags: command-line, bash

I wrote this simple script to check whether some of the specific ports are open or not.

```
#!/bin/bash    
prt=(8080,22,53)
for i in "${prt[@]}"
do
  nc -vz 127.0.0.1 $i
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then  
    echo "succeeded"
    echo $i
    break
  else
    echo "refused"
  fi
done
```

It should loop through the list of ports and print the first open port and then break from the loop. Except 8080 all other ports are open in my system and should in theory output `succeeded 22`. But instead of doing that this is the  output its giving

```
nc: port number invalid: 8080,22,53
refused
```

Comment: When you have a shell problem, a good first step is to cut and paste your code into
[shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/).  In this case, as in many  cases, it would have solved your problem quite quickly.

Answer (score 3):

`man bash` says:

> Arrays  are  assigned  to  using  compound  assignments  of  the  form name=(value<sub>1</sub>  ...  value<sub>n</sub>),  where  each   value   is   of   the   form [subscript]=string.

So to populate your array, you should rather do:

```bsh
prt=(8080 22 53)
```

I would do the task as follows:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
prt=(8080 22 53)
for i in "${prt[@]}"; do
  if nc -vz 127.0.0.1 $i; then
    echo -e succeeded\\n$i
    break
  else
    echo refused
  fi
done
```